# @QueryParam not parsing parameter after anchor ('#')

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I've noticed a weird behaviour in @QueryParam annotation from javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

With reference to the snippet of code below, when I set the url to something like:

```
http://host:port/services/serv123?test=OK
```

I can retrieve the value of 'test' as expected.

However, when I set the url to something like:

```
http://host:port/services/serv123#top?test=OK
```

@QueryParam("test") returns **null**.

Here is the code I am using. Each annotation is explicitly imported.

```
@Path("/services")
public class Services {
[...]
    @GET
    @Path("/{srvID}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public ServicesView getServiceDetailPage(@PathParam("srvID") String srvId, 
                                             @QueryParam("test") String test) {
        [...]
        return new ServicesView([...]);
    }
[...]
}
```

I have tested this in Dropwizard 0.9.1 (and included Jersey)

Please note:

- I'm interested in the explanation of the behaviour, not in a workaround (I have already a couple and can post them if someone is interested).
- To my knowledge, `http://host:port/services/serv123#top?test=OK` is a perfectly legitimate url and @QueryParam should be able to handle it (I'm happy to be proven wrong, just explain why it would not be a legal url).
- For the sake of testing, I have tried also encoding '#' into %23%3F but, as expected, it did not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: your assumpion that `/serv123#top?test=OK` is legitimate is correct, but your assumption that `test=OK` would be part of the query string is wrong. Anything after `#` is client side stuff. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
http://host:port/services/serv123#top?test=OK
```

use

```
http://host:port/services/serv123?test=OK#top
```

if you want `?test=OK` to be a query parameter instead of part of the anchor.